# Setting/Changing an .NET application's TimeZone

Tags: .net, reflection, timezone

Is there a way to set a .NET application's TimeZone to a value other than the OS's TimeZone?

For instance, I am using my application on an OS with Central Standard Time set, and I would like the app to behave as if it were in Eastern Standard Time, without having to manually convert all DateTimes in my application using a method like *TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId()*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, I don't believe there's any way of doing this. It's not like the time zone is set on a per thread basis like the culture. For instance, I believe that DateTime.ToLocalTime will *always* use the system time zone

However, I wouldn't use `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId` everywhere. I'd expose a property of type `TimeZoneInfo` which represented the appropriate time zone - or set up a helper class to convert where you need to.

Depending on your app, you may well find that if you choose the right points at which to convert the data (which *isn't* always a case of just keeping it in UTC everywhere apart from the UI layer) you don't have as many conversions to perform as you might expect.

Comment: We ended up abstracting the TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId to one of our DateTime helper classes, so we didn't need to expose the "Eastern Standard Time" constant everywhere in our code