# How to set univeral timezone for entire application in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, timezone

How can I set Universal timezone for entire application.

So that even if the timezone is changed, the application should show time as per universal timezone.

So is it possible to set entire application timezone?

Comment: It is a bit late to ask, but please tell me how is my question unclear. Garath  gave the perfect answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot (You could look at Jon Skeet response in following thread: [Setting/Changing an .NET application's TimeZone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120325/setting-changing-an-net-applications-timezone)). 
So you have two options:

1. Everywhwer use `DateTime.ToUniversalTime` ([MSDN description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime.aspx))
2. Create your own class which represents `DateTime` and use it instead
3. You can use one more trick. You can mock DateTime with for example Microsoft Fakes. Look more here: [Using shims to isolate your application from other assemblies for unit testing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/hh549176.aspx)

Comment: Can you Inherit DateTime? It is struct

Comment: @SriramSakthivel you are right. I updated my response.

Comment: How about `DateTime.UtcNow` much better right? since `DateTime.Now` internally uses `DateTime.UtcNow` to calculate local time

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is to create a `localization` class which will return DateTime in your prefered timezone. In your application, you should use this class and not `DateTime.Now` when you want to display date and time:

```
class Localization
{

    public Localization(string timeZoneId = "UTC")
    {
        TimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneId);
    }

    public virtual TimeZoneInfo TimeZone { get; set; }

    public DateTime Now
    {
        get
        {
            return     TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZone)
        }
    }
}
```

You can make above class singleton if you want only one static timezone in your application.

```
var locale = new Localization(); // default is UTC, provide yours.
var now = locale.Now;
```

Answer (score -1):

> How can I set Universal timezone for entire application?

Use the following code:

```
TimeZone zone =  TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
DateTime universal = zone.ToUniversalTime(DateTime.Now);
```